# Dapper Querylist return type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

My code looks like this;

```
 using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    var result = cnn.QuerySingle(sql, parameters);

    return result;
}
```

Its inside a method inside a class but that shouldn't matter. QuerySingle is said to return a dynamic type, but I have never worked with this before. When I debug this code, what it returns is something like this;

```
{{DapperRow, Tcode = 'eeeee', Hashedpw = 'NF886jMDl5imyMj0ThDIxA==', Salt = 'Z+HHq6Rt60FPnAf80Lg4Dg=='}}
```

How should I read this? Are they key-value pairs because the logic behind that doesn't work, it doesn't work like a list or an array. Im completly lost and have no idea what this returns. I only need the values, not the dapperrow, tcode, hashedpw and salt. So bassicly, the return I would need is

```
['eeeee', 'NF886jMDl5imyMj0ThDIxA==','Z+HHq6Rt60FPnAf80Lg4Dg==']
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you are using weak typed `QuerySingle()`, which will always return key value pair result. If you want to retrieve only values you should use **strongly typed** `QuerySingle()` like this.

```
var result= connection.QuerySingle<TYPE>(sql, parameters);
```

EDIT: If i got you right

you can define class for example

```
public class SomeClass 
{
  public string Salt {get;set;}
  public string TCode {get;set;}
  public string Hashedpw {get;set;}
}
```

And you can use this in the code like this `QuerySingle<SomeClass>` if you are returning multiple result in that case obviously you have to use like this `QuerySingle<List<SomeClass>>()`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: And how would I go about putting this in a list<string> or a string array?

Comment: @coder if you're returning a single column that *is* a string, and multiple rows, then: `var result = connection.Query<string>(sql, parameters).AsList();`; if you are returning multiple columns, then you'd need to give more context

Comment: @coder for example, another lazy way of doing this is "value tuples": `var row = connection.QuerySingle<(string tcode, string pwhash, string salt)>(sql, parameters);` - then look at `row.tcode`, `row.pwhash` etc (this example is one row, multiple columns)

Comment: I am indeed returning multiple columns from one row. The function I call takes in a tcode, which I look up in my database. When found, the function should return a list, or an array etc. with the tcode, the hashed password and the salt.

Comment: @coder why do you need a list/array/etc if you're only fetching one row? again: see the value-tuple example above, or Thundter's answer (which make So_oP's usage of `<TYPE>` more explicit). List/array = multiple rows. A single row should be one struct or class with multiple *properties*

Comment: I got it fixed with the solution in your second comment, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [link](https://dapper-tutorial.net/querysingle) for help on QuerySingle

If you create another class, something like this ...

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Tcode { get; set; }
    public string Hashedpw { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
}
```

... and changed your QuerySingle call to something like this ...

```
var result = cnn.QuerySingle<TestClass>(sql, parameters);
```

... a call like ...

```
Debug.WriteLine(result.Tcode);
```

... would result in `eeeee` comming out of your Debug window

Does that help?

Comment: ...too many ellipses... Would you mind... removing some of them...? Or better yet, all of them ...

Comment: I used something like this as suggested in the comments on a different answer. Thank you